# Boardman hydraulic disc brake lever fully lose

Tags: brakes

Brake Lever fully loose and not acting on the piston.  Circlip off so How to fix?

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. Please add more details to your question. As it stands it is too vague and is in peril of being flagged and deleted.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to bleed the brakes ?